# Gradle: BuildListener#buildStarted(Gradle) has been deprecated

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have the following code in my build.gradle. It's just a library(submodule) that will become a gradle dependency after pass my CI.

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
buildscript { scriptHandler ->
    apply from: 'common.gradle', to: scriptHandler
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    ...
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.library' //THIS IS THE LINE 38 in my code
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'net.researchgate.release'
apply from: "ci_testing.gradle"
... more android gradle code
```

The common.gradle file

```
repositories {
    ...
}
dependencies {
    ...
}
```

After run the command ./gradlew assemble I have a successful execution and a warning pointing the line 38

$ ./gradlew assembleSmeRelease --warning-mode all

```
> Configure project :
BuildListener#buildStarted(Gradle) has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0.
at build_8awlr5p8utk85ta3u2n2otdz2.run(/pathToMyLib/build.gradle:38)
(Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)
```

I've found this solution (from year 2012) in https://discuss.gradle.org/t/usage-of-apply-from-in-buildscript-scope/1844/5

Comment: That doesn't seem like something you should be worried about unless you wrote the `com.android.library` plugin. This looks like something the authors of the plugin should handle

Comment: Having the same issue. @smac89 I agree but my app cannot build without the fix.